# Pushing float to object transforms it into a string

Tags: javascript, json, casting

I am using the following code:

```
entries.category[newcat].subcategory[newsub].items[n] = {
            name: $("#name").val(),
            shortcut: $("#short").val(),
            description: $("#desc").val(),
            price: parseFloat($("#price").val()).toFixed(2),
            vat: parseFloat($("#vat").val()).toFixed(2)
        };
```

Yet, when I immediately check using `JSON.stringify`, both `price` and `VAT` are appended as strings i.e. "10.50" (rather than 10.50).

**QUESTION**: how do I make sure that price and VAT are stored as float?

Many thanks!

Comment: Any chance you checked the documentation for `Number.prototype.toFixed` before using it? "Returns

A string representation of numObj that does not use exponential notation and has exactly digits digits after the decimal place." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `toFix(2)` coverts the result back to string. To maintain the value as float, you need to pass the result of `toFix(2)` into another `parseFloat`

```
parseFloat(parseFloat($("#vat").val()).toFixed(2))
```

Comment: "you need to pass the result of toFix(2) into another parseFloat" --- it makes no sense

Comment: It does make sense.

Comment: @trincot it does not surely.

Answer (score 2):

Use the unitary `+` to convert the string values. Input element values are always strings, and even if you apply *parseFloat*, but then apply *toFixed* to that again, you turn the number back to string. Assuming you want to keep the *toFixed* call for limiting the number of decimals, use the `+` to do a final coercion to a number:

```
entries.category[newcat].subcategory[newsub].items[n] = {
    name: $("#name").val(),
    shortcut: $("#short").val(),
    description: $("#desc").val(),
    price: +parseFloat($("#price").val()).toFixed(2),
    vat: +parseFloat($("#vat").val()).toFixed(2)
};
```

To avoid the conversion from string-to-float-to-string-to-float, you could write:

```
    price: Math.round($("#price").val()*100)/100,
```

... etc, to achieve the same end result. `Math.round` will coerce the argument to `float`.

Comment: @zerkms: Rounding to 2 decimals.

Comment: There is `Math.round` designed for rounding.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't forbid the OP to use *toFixed* for that.

Comment: But it does not turn it into something that makes any sense.

Comment: I don't know why you are saying that. If the original value is "1.23456", then parseFloat will first make it 1.23456, then toFixed will make it "1.23" and the addtional + will make it 1.23. I don't see the problem, except that there are many ways to achieve the same.

Comment: The problem is in expressing intentions: tricky code is worse than idiomatic/straight code. I don't know in what universe one would use double type conversion instead of using a function that was designed specifically for some purpose.

Comment: I agree with that point about idiomatic code. I think I have misunderstand what you mean when you say "what is the point", and "it does not make sense".

Comment: You are quicker ;)